# Problem selecting one row from Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am writing an application for Android in kotlin. I have a Room database with an entity like

```
@Entity(tableName = "mt")
data class Mt(
    @PrimaryKey val trappnr: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name="stn") val stn: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="sortorder") val sortOder: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name="security") val security: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name="torkatMotor") val torkatMotor: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name="tvattatMotor") val tvattatMotor : Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name="tvattatMrum") val tvattatMrum: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name="tagitSopor") val tagitSopor: Boolean
)
```

In my DAO I do the following query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM mt WHERE trappnr == :trappnr")
suspend fun getMt(trappnr: String): Mt
```

I have enabled logging in my Room database and gets the following on ryunning the query above:

```
SQL Query: SELECT * FROM mt WHERE trappnr == ? SQL Args: [63301]
```

The result is always, no matter what I have done, an empty enitity.

I know the primary key exists because I get it when I read all rows in the table.

Any help on what I am doing wrong?

I am using androidx, Kotlin and Compose.

Comment: The code works fine (copied and pasted code ran fine but using the main thread and therefore  the function was not suspended). Your issue is either that the row does not exist or especially as you say that the data does exist, that you are not observing the result correctly as it is running on off the main thread.

Comment: Solved the problem. I now get the data all the way to a Compose function.